# Getting TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc add

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I'm a beginner to python and machine learning . I get below error when i try to fit data into statsmodels, please help me resolve this issue........

```
# Plotting the KDE Plot 
sns.kdeplot(x.loc[(x['gender']==1),'pixel_per_image'], color='r', shade=True, Label='Male') 
  
sns.kdeplot(x.loc[(x['gender']==0),'pixel_per_image'], color='b', shade=True, Label='Female') 
  
plt.xlabel('Avg pixel value per image') 
plt.ylabel('Probability Density') 
plt.title('Kernel Density Estimate plot to visualize probability density at different values in a continuous variable\n')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe your `'pixel_per_image'` column contains strings instead of numbers?  Try to [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67772067/edit) some dummy test data to your question to create a reproducible example. When you mention an error, it is important to state the exact line that causes it, preferably adding the full error trace to the post.

Comment: ooh it worked,thank you!!